# Jenkins. Running automated tests for code check-in

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm totally new to Jenkins(CI) and I am not able to understand one thing.

1. There is a repository on Github(ABC) where the developers check-in their code, makes changes etc. Suppose, let's say they are building a website www.abcd.com, and they use this repository for making code changes for the above website.
2. I'm a tester and I use another repository on Github(XYZ), where I have stored my automated tests built using TestNG and Maven.

The thing that I am not able to understand is how do we tell Jenkins to keep an eye on repository ABC, and that for any code changes, start running the tests from repository XYZ.

I have seen endless tutorials online, where they actually just enter the path of repository(XYZ, i.e automated tests)in Jenkins(Freestyle or Maven project), build them and run them(It's as good as running the same tests from Maven or Eclipse, as they don't run the tests against any code check-in). I want to know how we specify the repository(ABC, i.e developers repository)in Jenkins, tell Jenkins to monitor it(i.e ABC) for any code changes, and if there are any code changes, then start running whatever tests are present in the XYZ repository automatically.

I'm a tester and I just want to understand how the above scenario works. I don't care about deploying build on remote machines etc. I'm happy to run these tests on my local machine.I would be grateful if someone could help me on this.

Comment: There is a set of plugins called Build Triggers. For example, Gerrit Trigger, it can monitor a gerrit server. When some event happens on some branch of some git repo, the job is triggered to run. Of course, the necessary parameters are passed to the job.

Comment: You could also just do the checkout in commandline. So setup the job to monitor the triggering repo. When a change happens in the command line specify the other repo to be checked out and executed.